# Counting ways of making groups

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

There are 20 people and 14 tables. So there are two parts of this problem.
a) On how many ways can these people sit at the tables, if none of them is alone. 
b) How many ways are there to make 4 groups (order is important) if there must be at least 2 people in a group.

I'm thinking of using inclusion-exclusion principle, but am stuck at formulating it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the second question have to do with the tables???

Comment: for the second question, jsut simply use only the number 20, people. Tables are needed for the first question. It's two part problem. a and b. I did state that...

Comment: Are the tables distinguishable or indistinguishable ?

Comment: distinguishable